# How to dump an object in Spooky JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs, spookyjs

In CasperJS it's easy to dump an object by using:

```
var utils = require('utils');
utils.dump(myObj);
```

How do I dump an object with spooky.js in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Spooky seems to run in Node so you can just use `console.log()` (like in the browser).

Comment: I've tried it , and since they are different scopes, you even need a hack in order to use console.log()

Comment: Console is in global so it seems spooky runs in a vm context.